Redis GET in Node-RED
I have a node with the following output:
{"task_id":"celery-task-meta-d024fe34-eb5a-4493-829c-41f1877cffed","_msgid":"aca5b7a07ef39fb3"}

I want to pass this task_id to a Redis node "node-red-contrib-redis" to get the updates: I tried every combination in the Topic/Key field, like: {{msg.task_id}}, {{task_id}}, msg.task_id. But without any success! But when copy paste the task_id into the Topic/Key field it will work: like celery-task-meta-d024fe34-eb5a-4493-829c-41f1877cffed. How to pass this dynamic value in the Redis node!


Can you edit the question to confirm which Node-RED redis node you are using (node-red-node-redis?)

node-red-contrib-redis

Are you sure, because that doesn't match the screenshot

Sure, it is node-red-contrib-redis

Looking at the source code for the node, it expects parameters to be in msg.payload and will not use any other fields

In the Topic/Key I am using msg.payload. But the output will be msg.payload : string[15] "[object Object]". What I want is to pass "celery-task-meta-a1baac72-f55a-42e2-ac78-f5c4e99f5a5e" which should give the result from the Redis node. Look at the first image in the question

The Topic/Key is either set to a string or the value of msg.topic it can not me pulled from any other field in the msg object.

Ok, if that so, I will make an endpoint using FastAPI or Flask to get the status from Redis. I will use a simple http function to do it instead of using Redis node.
